# Nginx: maximum number of locations as specified in nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx, conf

Is there a maximum number of locations that nginx can handle in nginx.conf?

Comment: Probably, but it's extremely unlikely the answer would be useful to you, since a `server` generally has fewer than five `location`s anyway. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Looking at OpenResty, which uses locations as "routes"

Comment: You should talk to the app developers, then, or read their web site (if you can!) or their source code. This doesn't seem to be an appropriate question for Server Fault.

Comment: @michael, the question isn't specific to the app in question, but is ultimately a general question about nginx configuration limits.

Answer (score 3):

It is only limited by your memory. Having very much locations will impact on performance of each request but not greatly.